# javascript for loop percentage calculation for every 12 months

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have tried to calculate some numbers using javascript for loop. But, couldn't get desired result.

Example, Base quantity is 10000 and percentage is 8.

First 12 months it should be,

> 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000
>   10000

Next 12 months, I have to calculate 8 percent of 10000 and add it to base quantity. 8 percent of 10000 is 800. So, output for next 12 month is,

> 10800 10800 10800 10800 10800 10800 10800 10800 10800 10800 10800
>   10800

Next 12 months, I have to calculate 8 percent of 10800 and add it to previous base quantity. 8 percent of 10800 is 864. So, output for next 12 month is,

> 11664 11664 11664 11664 11664 11664 11664 11664 11664 11664 11664
>   11664

Next 12 months, I have to calculate 8 percent of 11664 and add it to previous base quantity. 8 percent of 11664 is 933.12. So, output for next 12 month is,

> 12597.12 12597.12 12597.12 12597.12 12597.12 12597.12 12597.12 12597.12 12597.12 12597.12 12597.12 12597.12

Tried below code so far,

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction() {
    l = 12;
    a = document.getElementById("base").value;
    hk = (a*document.getElementById("per").value)/100;


    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      if(i % 12 === 0) {
          a = Number(document.getElementById("base").value) + Number(hk);
      }
    }
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += a;


  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <span>Base</span>
    <input type="text" id="base" value="10000" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Percentage</span>
    <input type="text" id="per" value="8" />
  </div>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>
```

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkf9ocme/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

- You need to keep track of updated value of `a`, hence, move it outside the function
- On every click, check value of `a`. If it is for the first time, pick it from the input field and for consecutive clicks, you can pick the same from the calculated value during previous execution
- To print the value 12 times, simply loop to prepare the resultant string.
- Finally append the string to the appropriate resultant element.

```js
var a;
function myFunction() {
  var l = 12;
  a = a || Number(document.getElementById("base").value);
  var hk = (a * document.getElementById("per").value) / 100;
  a += Number(hk);
  var r = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      r += a + " ";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += r + "<br/>";


}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Base</span>
  <input type="text" id="base" value="10000" />
</div>
<div>
  <span>Percentage</span>
  <input type="text" id="per" value="8" />
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

You can also have the iterations either hard-coded in code or can pick from html as following.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var l = 12;
  var a = Number(document.getElementById("base").value);
  var years = Number(document.getElementById("years").value);
  var r = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < years; i++) {
    if(i) {
      var hk = (a * document.getElementById("per").value) / 100;
      a += Number(hk);
    }
    
    for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) {
      r += a + " ";
    }
    r += "<br/>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += r;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Base</span>
  <input type="text" id="base" value="10000" />
</div>
<div>
  <span>Percentage</span>
  <input type="text" id="per" value="8" />
</div>
<div>
  <span>Years</span>
  <input type="text" id="years" value="4" />
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this

```js
function myFunction() {
  var l = 12;
  var cycle = document.getElementById("cycle").value;
  var a = document.getElementById("base").value;
  var hk = parseFloat((a * document.getElementById("per").value) / 100);
  for (let j = 0; j < cycle; j++) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br>For next 12 months<br>"
    a = Number(a) + Number(hk);
    hk = parseFloat((a * document.getElementById("per").value) / 100);
    for (var i = 1; i <= l; i++) {

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '<br>' + a;

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Base</span>
  <input type="text" id="base" value="10000" />
</div>
<div>
  <span>Percentage</span>
  <input type="text" id="per" value="8" />
</div>
<div>
  <span>Cycles</span>
  <input type="text" id="cycle" value="4" />
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: For how many cycles you have to repeat it. Like in the question you have shown 4 12 month cycles

Comment: Yes. 4 cycles. But, it will depend upon user input.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a;
function myFunction() {
    l = 12;
    a = a || document.getElementById("base").value;
    hk = (a*document.getElementById("per").value)/100;

    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += ' ' + a;
    }
    a = Number(a) + Number(hk);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '<br>'

  }
  
  function call() {
      b = document.getElementById("cycles").value;
      if (b) {
        for (var i = 0; i < b; i++) {
          myFunction();
        }
      } else {
        myFunction();
      }
  }
```

```html
<div>
    <span>Base</span>
    <input type="text" id="base" value="10000" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Percentage</span>
    <input type="text" id="per" value="8" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Years</span>
    <input type="text" id="cycles" value="4" />
  </div>
  
  <button onclick="call()">Click</button>
  
  <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Can I get the output for 4 cycles in single click?

Comment: you can give as many iterations you want to the `call` function there so that you get `n` cycles as you wish.

Comment: for your user input of number of cycles, you can have another input referenced in the call function instead of my way of passing it as parameter and then run the loop based on that value. Additionally, I just wanted to keep the actual logic and loop logic separate.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried with Javascript to replicate the output.
Considering the upper loop to be a dependent number of times you want to calculate.

```js
let baseValue = 10000
const basePercent = 0.08
const months = 12
let numberOfYears = 5
let skipFirstYear = false
for(let j = 0; j< numberOfYears; j++ ) {
    if(j === 1) {
     skipFirstYear = true
    }
    if(skipFirstYear) {
      baseValue += baseValue * basePercent
    }
    for(let i = 0; i<months; i++) {
     console.log(baseValue)
    }
}
```